# count down timers in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How do I find out the most commonly or popularly used count down timer in jquery. I have been looking into this (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/countdown2) but not sure if this is well supported. Is there a some kind of a ranking system for the jquery plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every plug-in has its star rating on jQuery page so you can use it as a reference.

Personaly, I used this one before: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html which is the same one you provided.

Answer (score 1):

See:

**[jQuery CountDown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)**

Ranking is available just below the name of the plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/countdown2

Answer (score 0):

Making a count down timer would be fairly easy.

```
<html>
<body>
    <span id="sample">10</span>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var countDownFrom = 10;
        var intervalId = setInterval(function()
        {
            if(countDownFrom == 0)
                clearInterval(intervalId);

            document.getElementById('sample').innerHTML = countDownFrom.toString(); 
            countDownFrom--;
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```